# Thymeleaf + Spring Checkboxes not binding

Tags: spring, checkbox, thymeleaf

Here's my snippets of code:

Vehicle Class:

```
// Duplicates
private Boolean regCard = true;
private Boolean decal;
private Boolean title;

public Boolean getRegCard() {
    return regCard;
}

public void setRegCard(Boolean regCard) {
    this.regCard = regCard;
}

public Boolean getDecal() {
    return decal;
}

public void setDecal(Boolean decal) {
    this.decal = decal;
}

public Boolean getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(Boolean title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
                        <form method="post" th:action="${flowExecutionUrl}" th:object="${customerModel.vehicle}">
                        <div class="duplicates">
                            <ul>
                                <li><label>What do you need to duplicate?</label>
                                    <div class="regTitle">
                                        <label>Registration Card 
                                            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{regCard}"/>
                                        </label> 
                                        <label>Decal 
                                            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{decal}"/>
                                        </label> 
                                        <div th:switch="*{vehicleType}"> 
                                            <div th:case="'BR'">
                                                <label>Title 
                                                    <input th:type="checkbox" th:field="*{title}"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btm-btn-row">
                            <div class="btm-btn-left">
                                <a th:href="@{'~' + ${flowExecutionUrl}(_eventId='back')}">back</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btm-btn-right">
                                <input type="submit" value="continue" name="_eventId_continue" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/IllinoisRVSWeb/main-flow?execution=e1s4">
                        <div class="duplicates">
                            <ul>
                                <li><label>What do you need to duplicate?</label>
                                    <div class="regTitle">
                                        <label>Registration Card 
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle.regCard1" name="vehicle.regCard" value="true" checked="checked" /><input type="hidden" name="_vehicle.regCard" value="on" />
                                        </label> 
                                        <label>Decal 
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle.decal1" name="vehicle.decal" value="true" /><input type="hidden" name="_vehicle.decal" value="on" />
                                        </label> 
                                        <div> 
                                            <div>
                                                <label>Title 
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle.title1" name="vehicle.title" value="true" /><input type="hidden" name="_vehicle.title" value="on" />
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btm-btn-row">
                            <div class="btm-btn-left">
                                <a href="/IllinoisRVSWeb/main-flow?execution=e1s4&amp;_eventId=back">back</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btm-btn-right">
                                <input type="submit" value="continue" name="_eventId_continue" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Problem:

The boolean values never get set upon submit. 
I've tried the other way. Using a List object and binding that variable to the checkboxes with the proper th:value="'SOMETEXT'" for each checkbox. But that object stays null as well.

As you see I set one value to true beforehand to see if it would show up on the html side. It was successful. so its at least retrieving the value, but its not setting it if its ever changed.

Also, as you can see, I tried using "th:value="checkbox"" to see if that helped. It did not.

Thymeleaf Version 2.1.4

Spring 4.1.4

Spring WebFlow 2.4.0

Any help or tips would be great.

Thanks

Comment: In another page of the site I'm developing, I was able to successfully use checkboxes and have the proper Boolean value sent to the back end. I'm comparing the two pages to see what I've done differently, but not seeing any differences at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIGH...Well I found out the solution.

I easily overlooked the WebFlow xml def file for the subflow and view state i was in.

What I had:

```
<view-state id="duplicate" view="duplicates">
    <transition on="continue" to="checkVehicleInfo" />
    <transition on="back" to="finished" />
</view-state>
```

What was missing as an attribute in the view-state:

```
model="customerModel"
```

This is needed for form submission when using Spring WebFlow

Answer (score 0):

I guess that possible solution is:

pass checkbox value as request parameter

```
<label>Registration Card
<input type="checkbox" name="retCardChecked"/>
```

and then catch it in the controller and set to the Vehicle object

```
@RequestParam("retCardChecked") boolean retCardChecked, ...
```

Comment: I'm using Spring WebFlow so I'm currently not implementing any controllers. If I can't find a proper solution to my issue, then I can use a controller for this instance. Though I rather stick to my design scheme, if possible.

Comment: And I'll go to have a look at  WebFlow ))